# Do I create a new Navigation Page or Content Page when making a tabbed application?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to create an application with tabs. I don't need the functionality of a Navigation page that allows me to go back to the last screen. I just want the tab bar to allow me to select one of five pages.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
public partial class MainPage : TabbedPage
{

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
```

My question is which of the following should I use.  Note that HomePage inherits from ContentPage.

```
        // this is the one the app uses now. Do I really need to NavigationPage and then inside that another page HomePage?
        var homePage = new NavigationPage(new HomePage())
        {
            Title = "Home",
            Icon = "ionicons_2_0_1_home_outline_25.png"
        };

        // I thought this would be better but ContentPage constructor cannot take an argument
        var homePage = new ContentPage(new HomePage())
        {
            Title = "Home",
            Icon = "ionicons_2_0_1_home_outline_25.png"
        };

        // this is my latest thought but would like to hear from others
        var homePage = new HomePage()
        {
            Title = "Home",
            Icon = "ionicons_2_0_1_home_outline_25.png"
        };

 Children.Add(homePage);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It's recommended that a `TabbedPage` should be populated with
>   `NavigationPage` and `ContentPage` instances only. This will help to ensure
>   a consistent user experience across all platforms.

The quote above is from the official [TabbedPage documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/tabbed-page#creating-a-tabbedpage).

1. You don't have to wrap a `ContentPage` by `NavigationPage` if it is not needed.
2. If `HomePage` is inheriting from a `ContentPage` then you can just create an instance of it and add to children the next way:

---

```
var homePage = new HomePage
{
    Title = "Home",
    Icon = "ionicons_2_0_1_home_outline_25.png"
};
Children.Add(homePage);
```

P.S.: [Official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/) has covered navigation topics quite nicely. Please get familiar with it.

Comment: Looking at the documentation I am still confused.  Why do they specify a navigation page with a SchedulePageCS inside.  Why not just make SchedulePageCS itself be a navigationPage?      var navigationPage = new NavigationPage (new SchedulePageCS ());

Comment: There is a difference between ContentPage and a NavigationPage. The docs demonstrate both approaches.